# Quiz for Flash CS4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to create a 10 question quiz in flash cs4.

I'm using radio buttons, but I need them to have a value that sums up a final score. That final score needs to be reflected on a different frame in the dynamic text.

How do I get the buttons to have value and sum them up for a final score?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need define score variable in first frame.

Create buttons for your quiz using this tutorial:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa3.html

Modify final score in handlers, every time when user clicks on button. Keep it unvisible until final frame.

Comment: Thank you, but I already looked at that page. I'm not sure how to modify a score in handlers or how to apply a score.

Comment: Check if event.target.value equals to proper answer and add (or subtract) points from score. Use different handler for every question.

Comment: Show me what you got.

Comment: I don't have anything yet. I have to so a project with no knowledge of actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered opening the code for the class you have for your button, and creating a `boolean` property that indicates whether or not the question is correct? Then, once the user presses the button, you can check whether or not `isCorrect` is `True`, and award points accordingly.

Comment: How do I create a boolean?